# C# WPF Controls within Controls and distinguishing LeftClick events!

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, events, click

I have UserControls within UserControls in WPF. This makes a tree structure starting from the root node.

I want to register for the event MouseLeftClickDown in all the UserControls. Left Clicking on a child control causes the event to fire for that control and all the parent controls that contain that child.

When I click a child, I don't want to fire the event for any parent controls, I just want it to fire for the child control clicked.

Comment: What if you mark the event as handled (EventArgs parameter) at the child level?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MouseDownEvent. The MouseEventArgs passed to the handler should have a Handled property that if it is set to true indicates that the event should not be passed on to the controls higher up in the hierarchy.